# Deploy InDesign file generator

Tags: c#, deployment, automation, adobe-indesign

I have been struggling with this so I decided to ask for your help.
I have a web page that calls ashx handler, which generates InDesgin file based on database entries.

On my dev machine works perfectly. Windows 10 x64 + Visual Studio 2017 community
When I deploy to the server however it doesn't open the app, but I can see it running in the tasks.

here is the code (reference added via VS to the local InDesign COM)

```
    using InDesign;

Type type = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("InDesign.Application.CC.2019", false);
dynamic applications = System.Activator.CreateInstance(type, true);

applications.ViewPreferences.HorizontalMeasurementUnits = idMeasurementUnits.idMillimeters;
applications.ViewPreferences.VerticalMeasurementUnits = idMeasurementUnits.idMillimeters;

// Set unit type
applications.ViewPreferences.HorizontalMeasurementUnits = idMeasurementUnits.idMillimeters;
applications.ViewPreferences.VerticalMeasurementUnits = idMeasurementUnits.idMillimeters;

// Create new document
applications.Documents.Add(true, applications.DocumentPresets.FirstItem());
dynamic doc = applications.ActiveDocument;

doc.Close();
doc = null;
applications.Quit();
```

and this is what I get on the server
Object reference not set to an instance of an object

```
System.Dynamic
System.NullReferenceException
at System.Dynamic.ExcepInfo.GetException()
   at System.Dynamic.ComRuntimeHelpers.CheckThrowException(Int32 hresult, ExcepInfo& excepInfo, UInt32 argErr, String message)
   at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , ComObject , idMeasurementUnits )
   at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute2[T0,T1,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1)
   at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute2[T0,T1,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1)
   at TestInDesign.Test.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) in C:\users\myuser\source\repos\TestInDesign\TestInDesign\Test.ashx.cs:line 55........System.Exception GetException()
```

this is the line --- `applications.ViewPreferences.HorizontalMeasurementUnits = idMeasurementUnits.idMillimeters;`

I have set the properties of the referenced com as embed interoop , do not copy local

What am I missing?
Thanks in advance

Comment: If I initiated the application like this InDesignApp applications = new InDesignApp(); I get an error of type Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).  But both machines are x64, and its been built for x64. So I am lost

Comment: And have you verified the 3rd party software is set up sufficiently, with the right versions, that you have all the permissions you might need, ect. have you tried writing a small console app to run on the server to test it actually will work in this new environment

Comment: Well, I did a short version just to initiate it and response.write each step etc. but still the same.
As to permissions, I don't know what to look for honestly. I did on system level full permissions to the account using the code. still the same. Let me check if the actual type library has limited access permissions

Comment: NOPE, I did it on both the application and the typelib. not the issue

Comment: I think its something to do with my web app having the rights to launch InDesign. How do I fix that?